# how to edit dropdown select option or change the type of select option to text type

Tags: html, angular, angular2-forms, angular4-forms

```
    <form [formGroup]="sampleEditForm" (ngSubmit)="sampleSubmit(sampleEditForm.value)">
    <md2-select placeholder="{{'Parameter'|translate:lang}}"  [formControl]="sampleEditForm.controls['parameterId']"  [(ngModel)]="parameterId" (change)="changeParam($event.value)" class="input_custom_width"  required>
        <md2-select-header>
            <md-input-container class="input_custom_width">
                <input mdInput type="text" placeholder="{{'Search'| translate:lang}}" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [(ngModel)]="searchParameter"/>
            </md-input-container>
        </md2-select-header>
        <md2-option *ngFor="let parameter of parametersAry | filterPipe : searchParameter" [value]="parameter.value">{{ parameter.name }}</md2-option>
    </md2-select>
    <md-card-actions align="start">
        <button md-raised-button type="submit" color="primary">Submit</button>
    </md-card-actions>
</form>
```

When I select an option from dropdown,I have to edit it or convert it to text type to edit.plz help me to sort out this.

Comment: please provide a [mcve] reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by toggling a boolean value using `*ngIf`.

This can be done with a status variable.
If the status is false, display dropdown. If an option gets selected, set the status to true. This will hide the dropdown and display the text Area/text box.

Answer (score 0):

```
<md2-option *ngFor="let parameter of parametersAry | filterPipe : searchParameter" [value]="parameter.value">
    <span
              *ngIf="!editing">
              {{parameter.name}}
        </span>
    <input autofocus *ngIf="editing" type="text" [value]="parameter.name" />
</md2-option>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think when you select an option from drop down, change event is triggered and on this change event you can write your code as per requirement

```
$("#selectId").change(function () {
//your code as per requirement
```

});